# Template restrictions - Need to change the color of Blog Title only

Tags: html, css, templates

My blog url: https://fashionindiar.blogspot.com

I have used Picture Window template for my blog, wherein separate Blog Description option is missing. I need different colors for my Blog Title and Blog Description. But while changing the blog title color under Customize->Advanced->Blog Title, the blog description color gets changed too. Same color is attributed to both (title and description), which is not my requirement. Further, I found that both are grouped together in HTML.

I applied the following CSS code (for my blog title) in Customize->Advanced->Add CSS:

h1{color: #ffffff;}

Consequently, it shows the desired result (the blog title color gets changed only) instantly and also under Template section. But the change is not effective on the web. I would like to know whether I need to put the above CSS code in style.css file (if it's available in blogger). If so, I would appreciate if you could let me know the file's location in blogger.

I need to change the color of my blog title only.

Looking forward to your reply.

Thank you.

Shampa Sengupta

Comment: color is coming from `a` tag. If you can go in css or find `fashion-india.html` line no. 213. just apply `.Header h1 a{ color: red }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `css` will do, try it

```
.Header h1 a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

So the css above is targeting `Header class` > `h1` > `a`